# Is it possible to have an optional group between two "any" groups in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex statement that looks like this:

`(.*)_(ce)_(.*)_([0-9]{8}).([A-Za-z]{1,20})(?:\\.[A-Za-z]{1,20})?`

It's supposed to group `(anything)_(ce)_(anything)_(some digits).(some_ext).(some_possible_ext)`.

So, this is a possible passing string:

`hello_ce_world_20192212.json.xml`.

The groups are:

```
1. hello
2. ce
3. world
4. 20192212
5. json
6. xml
```

I now want to make the (ce) optional, and make the regex look like this:

`(.*)_(ce_)?(.*)_([0-9]{8}).([A-Za-z]{1,20})(?:\\.[A-Za-z]{1,20})?`

Such that this would pass: `hello_ce_world_20192212.json.xml`, and the groups would be:

```
1. hello
2. ce
3. world
4. 20192212
5. json
6. xml
```

And this would pass: `hello_world_20192212.json.xml`, and the groups would be:

```
1. hello
3. world
4. 20192212
5. json
6. xml
```

So, the regex works! The problem is, when (ce_) is present in the text being evaluated, it is included in group one. So,  `hello_ce_world_20192212.json.xml` passes the regex, but the groups are:

```
1. hello_ce
3. world
4. 20192212
5. json
6. xml
```

This violate the constraint I mentioned above. Not sure how to fix the regex to have it do this; I suspect because it is in between two `(.*)` groups, it won't work OR my regex needs to be more specific. Just thinking about it logically makes me understand that it's unlikely I can achieve what I want... but maybe someone out there has more understanding. Any help?

I have found this [website](https://regex101.com/) helpful for testing out what groups are where and stuff.

Comment: Wouldn't `(.*?)` as the first group solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the first group capture a non-greedy one with the `?`. This regex should do what you need:

```
(.*?)_(ce)?_?(.*)_([0-9]{8})\.([A-Za-z]{1,20})?\.([A-Za-z]{1,20})?
```

as tested in https://regex101.com/r/MZqDPd/3

Also note the adjustments to make `ce` optional yet captured, without the `_`. This opens up to cases where either might be missing and still pass the regex. Be aware of this.

Comment: My bad, my regex was the correct regex, but you are correct, a date is supposed to come after `world`. Will edit post accordingly

Comment: Fair enough. I'll update my solution.

Comment: The solution worked when I updated it. Thank you, that was smart. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Hey, is it possible to include the `_` in the (ce) group, and achieve the same grouping results?

Comment: Yes, try this: `(.*?)_(?:(ce)_)?(.*)_([0-9]{8})\.([A-Za-z]{1,20})?\.([A-Za-z]{1,20})?`